# How to trigger a 2010 workflow on all existing list items OR use Powershell instead to copy data?

Tags: powershell, designer-workflow, custom-timer-job, copy-item

I have a SP 2013 list with 100 existing items.  I have full SP Admin rights.  There is a simple 'copy item' workflow which copies data from the source list to the destination list - both list have many of the same field names so the data will copy over.

I could manually run the workflows one-by-one via the User Interface (UI), but that is slow.  Is there a way of running the workflow on all list items at once?

Otherwise I understand that I could use Powershell or a Timer Job on the server instead. - what are the Pros and Cons?  Is there a simple Powershell script which I could adapt for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Create Item in this list** command in SP Designer can do this.  I used a 2010 workflow.

In the source list you will create the workflow, select your destination list (my destination list is called 'OH Light'.

In the dialogue box click on the existing fields to modify them or select 'Add' to add additional fields to copy.

- You can use this dialogue box to select the sourcefield:destinationfield to instruct the workflow to select values to copy and set the destination field to copy the value to.
- You can also use this method to set the Content Type (if you are using them).

[image: Define fields:fields in source:destination lists]